# What is the reasoning behind BitTorrent KRPC using BEncode instead of BSON?

Tags: json, encoding, rpc, bittorrent, bson

The [Mainline DHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_DHT), used in [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_protocol) to distribute lists of peers, implements a custom RPC protocol called KRPC. KRPC consists of BEncoded dictionaries, which are essentially a more compact form of JSON.

Is there any benefit of using BEncode over something like BSON (or even just compressing the data)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that `bencode` is being used for historical reasons and to lighten the burden on developers wanting to implement the DHT extension. Since all BitTorrent clients must have a working `bencode` implementation to work with torrent files (which are simply bencoded dictionaries of metadata), implementing the DHT with `bencode` would require no new project dependencies.

Also, consider that the DHT is using `bencode` along with binary encoding. Among others, the 26 byte node identifier string (20 bytes for the node-id, 6 bytes for the ipv4 address / port) is being stored as a binary string (see: http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html#contact-encoding), so in-effect, there is already some minimal data-compression that is happening.